# Installing Shrew VPN for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, vpn

I am new to using Ubuntu machine.

I am trying to install Shrew VPN software for my Ubuntu machine with following details:

1. Version- 16.04
2. 64 bit

I installed the Ubuntu 12.04 version of Shrew VPN from https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/ike-qtgui/

Did all the necessary setting to add a new site configuration but trying to connect, I am getting the error: "negotiation timout occurred"

For reference:

```
remote id configured
pre-shared key configured
bringing up tunnel ...
negotiation timout occurred
tunnel disabled
detached from key daemon
```

How could I possibly solve this problem?

Comment: That old version is likely NOT to work. You can try https://techedemic.com/2015/10/14/installing-shrewsoft-vpn-on-ubuntu-14-04/ but still you may find dependencies problems. Post a question about it if you must.

Comment: Yeah, I am getting an error on step-3: installing dependencies. 

E: Unable to locate package libqt4-core
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-gui

Comment: You can try what's offered for your current Ubuntu release. I haven't checked before because I wrongly assumed you went looking for it because you dind't find it with the Ubuntu Software app/tool. Now I just checked and it's there.

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be prebuilt binaries for most Ubuntu releases here:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ike

So all I needed to do was

```
sudo apt-get install ike-qtgui
```

If you don't find this helpful, try building from source as described [in this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586701/5002496) (Unfortunately didn't work on my Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: oh oh, broken link to SO